# WrapPanel child taking full width of parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two elements inside a WrapPanel, a button and another WrapPanel. The button has a dynamic width. The issue is that the child WrapPanel assumes the full width of the parent WrapPanel, overflowing to the right because of the Button on its left.

[image: WrapPanel overflowing]

```
    <WrapPanel Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button x:Name="BookCover" Click="ChangeImageFile" Margin="10">
            button style and content
        </Button>
        <WrapPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBox Text="New Book"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos iusto graece consetetur cu, an dicam nonumy volutpat qui, usu at nullam alienum. Est suas autem augue ad, integre vituperatoribus quo id, delicata gloriatur pro ei. Vel at nisl decore, ut eum altera commune. Nec at agam menandri, putant insolens suavitate ei mei, ea possim veritus mea. Nec nemore iuvaret detracto at, quodsi consectetuer pri id. Integre suscipit voluptua no pro, nonumes incorrupte ut mea. Delenit democritum vel in, quem tale everti vim id, id vis melius necessitatibus. Paulo signiferumque per te. Cu mei modus exerci partiendo, ad iudico adolescens mea, et stet integre civibus mea." TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>
        </WrapPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
```

How can I make it fit inside the window?

Comment: Why use WrapPanel for this? you should be fine by just using Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you should be good by using `Grid` something like:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> <!--to fit to the content-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <!--fill all the remaining-->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="BookCover" Click="ChangeImageFile" Margin="10">
            button style and content
        </Button>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
            <TextBox Text="New Book"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos iusto graece consetetur cu, an dicam nonumy volutpat qui, usu at nullam alienum. Est suas autem augue ad, integre vituperatoribus quo id, delicata gloriatur pro ei. Vel at nisl decore, ut eum altera commune. Nec at agam menandri, putant insolens suavitate ei mei, ea possim veritus mea. Nec nemore iuvaret detracto at, quodsi consectetuer pri id. Integre suscipit voluptua no pro, nonumes incorrupte ut mea. Delenit democritum vel in, quem tale everti vim id, id vis melius necessitatibus. Paulo signiferumque per te. Cu mei modus exerci partiendo, ad iudico adolescens mea, et stet integre civibus mea." TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Worked. Using grid columns seems like a more viable option than StackPanel.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably caused by `Orientation="Vertical"`.
As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.orientation(v=vs.110).aspx), 
If the Orientation property is set to Horizontal, child content forms horizontal rows first and if necessary forms vertical stacks of rows. If the Orientation property is set to Vertical, child content is first positioned in a vertical column, and if there is not enough space, wrapping occurs and additional columns in the horizontal dimension are added.

Here you have set the Orientation to Vertical and has not set a default width to the Wrappanel. This causes the issue. The wrapping occurs vertically and causes the child content to move out of the visible area.
Either define a constant width to the wrappanel or fit to the window width like : `Width="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Width}"` or try consider removing the `Orientation="Vertical"`.

**EDIT**
I am including a solution to fix your issue. The method is to use a `Grid` inside parent wrappanel to equaly divide space between button and content into 2 equal columns. Check if this helps.

```
<WrapPanel Height="200"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="BookCover"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="10"
                Click="ChangeImageFile">
            button style and content
        </Button>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
            <TextBox Text="New Book" />
            <TextBox Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos iusto graece consetetur cu, an dicam nonumy volutpat qui, usu at nullam alienum. Est suas autem augue ad, integre vituperatoribus quo id, delicata gloriatur pro ei. Vel at nisl decore, ut eum altera commune. Nec at agam menandri, putant insolens suavitate ei mei, ea possim veritus mea. Nec nemore iuvaret detracto at, quodsi consectetuer pri id. Integre suscipit voluptua no pro, nonumes incorrupte ut mea. Delenit democritum vel in, quem tale everti vim id, id vis melius necessitatibus. Paulo signiferumque per te. Cu mei modus exerci partiendo, ad iudico adolescens mea, et stet integre civibus mea." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: The elements do not align as I want them to if Orientation isn't Horizontal. Thanks for pointing out the issue. Didn't find a solution yet though (Constant width is not an option)

Comment: @AndreiIlie, check my answer.

Comment: @AndreiIlie : As Bolu suggested, you could try using a grid. But grid cannot provide what you expect from a WrapPanel which is **same as StackPanel but it wraps the elements accordingly to size of the form.  The control in Wrap Panel is shifted to the next line automatically if the form size is getting changed.**  But using a grid will make things worse only. The thing is button is inside the parent and the rest of the contents are inside the child . So only the space left after button is used. Hence its better to specify a minimum width to achieve what you need.